# Create Dictionary<byte,string> from Enum value and its display name

Tags: c#, enums

**solved**

 I would like to create a generic function that will return a dictionary of enum values (can be generic too e.g. int/byte/short) and the display name attribute.

 What i have come so far with is :

 Get dictionary of names and values :

```
class EnumHelper ...
public static Dictionary<N, string> GetEnumDictionary<T, N>(bool displayName = false)
        {
            return  Enum
                .GetValues(typeof(T))
                .Cast<T>()
                .ToDictionary(t => (N)(object)t, t => t.ToString());
        }
```

Which i use like this :

```
var statuses = EnumHelper.GetEnumDictionary<LockStatus,int>();
```

And get the display name attribute per enum value :

```
public static class EnumExtensions
    {


        /// <summary>
        ///     A generic extension method that aids in reflecting 
        ///     and retrieving any attribute that is applied to an `Enum`.
        /// </summary>
        public static TAttribute GetAttribute<TAttribute>(this Enum enumValue)
                where TAttribute : Attribute
        {
            return enumValue.GetType()
                            .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
                            .First()
                            .GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>();
        }
    }
```

Which i use like this :

```
var display = ((TicketEvent)n.Event).GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();
n.EventName = display.Name;
```

But i just can combine them. 

 Any thoughts ?

Comment: It would be awesome to have a [mcve] with some sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: I understand both things separately. But what are you trying to achieve when you "combine them"? What is your end goal?

Comment: title - Create Dictionary<byte,string> from Enum value and its display name

Comment: You can do it like this for example: `typeof(T).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                .ToDictionary(c => (N)c.GetValue(null), c => c.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().Name)`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my `ExtensionMethod`:

#### Extension Method

```
/// <summary>
/// includes all extensions for <see cref="Enum"/> operations.
/// </summary>
public static class EnumExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Retreives the Description as string. If there is no Description. You will get null.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum obj)
    {
        object[] attribArray = obj.GetType().GetField(obj.ToString()).GetCustomAttributes(false);

        if (attribArray.Length == 0)
            return null;

        if (attribArray[0] is DescriptionAttribute attrib)
        {
            return attrib.Description;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Usage

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    [Description("It's Lorem")]
    Lorem,
    [Description("It's Ipsum")]
    Ipsum
}

string description = MyEnum.Ipsum.GetDescription();
```

So just extend my method. Iterate through all fields and return the string.

Answer (score 0):

ohhhh shame .....

 The reason it was not working was i didn't declare the enum as byte.

 After fixing it this code is working :

```
return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
        .Cast<T>()
        .ToDictionary(t => (N)(object)t, t => ((t as Enum).GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()).Name);
```

Comment: I keep getting invalid cast exception so i thought it was because of my code.